# How to read a command's output while it is running?

Tags: bash, shell-script, progress-information

If a command were to output, say, a progress bar that updates live, until it stops, and I wanted to constantly obtain the percentage of said progress bar and display it in a GUI such as zenity, how would one go about to do this.

I do know how to obtain it when the command ends, storing it in a variable. This is what most questions on this site ask, but I want to do it while the command is running.

I imagine it is possible as many apps do it already, such as many game launchers, app stores, and such. Once again, how would I go on to do the same?

Comment: `expect` might help. Read `man expect`.

Comment: If you already know how to obtain the percentage then just pipe it to `zenity` instead capturing it  to a variable.

Comment: It depends on the format of the progress bar and how it's written to the console. Is it a sort of ASCII graphic progress bar, and how the percentage is written. If the percentage is always on the same line (i.e uses the carriage return to get back to the beginning of the line, clears it and rewrite the new number without a new line) it would be difficult to do that. So it really depends on the original program and the output format.

Comment: It is similar to a `wget` progress bar

Comment: @annahri I only know how to do it once the command has ended, not while it's running

Comment: Do you know what a pipe is?

Comment: You need to either know (or be able to estimate) how long the command(s) will take to run or know/estimate roughly how much output it will generate. You can then use that knowledge/guess to increment the progress bar at appropriate intervals.    e.g. if you know/guess it'll take about 5 minutes, increment the bar every ~3 seconds.  Traditionally, you're supposed to do this until you reach ~98% at the 5 minute mark, and then sit on that for the remaining 15-20 minutes it takes to run. i.e. first build up the user's hope at how fast the bar is moving then smash them down into a pit of despair.

Comment: (and if you can pull off that hope->despair trick multiple times in just one run, you win the Microsoft Installer Gold Star Achievement.  Platinum Star if you can work in some inexplicable drops in "% complete")

Comment: If a command already outputs a progress bar, I don't quite understand why do you need to pass it to zenity to display another progress bar?

Comment: @raj I guess he wants a ncurses-like interface, hence zenity.

Answer (score 2):

Sending a command's output to another command in real-time is usually done using pipes.

If the progress bar format looks like that of `wget` as you say in comments which looks like:

```
[...]
 92750K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 12% 3.81M 3m31s
 92800K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 12% 4.36M 3m29s
 92850K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 12% 4.05M 3m28s
 92900K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 12% 4.04M 3m26s
 92950K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 12% 3.86M 3m25s
 93000K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 12% 3.98M 3m24s
 93050K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 12% 3.86M 3m23s
 93100K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 12% 3.31M 3m22s
[...]
```

When the output doesn't go to a tty, then you can do (assuming GNU `grep`):

```
wget ... 2>&1 |
  grep --line-buffered -Po ' \K\d+(?=%)' |
  zenity --progress
```

That is, extract the percentage number, and send it to `zenity`'s stdin.

Note:

- `2>&1` as `wget` prints its progress bar on stderr (very common).
- `--line-buffered` as otherwise, given that its output doesn't go to a tty device, `grep` would otherwise buffer its output.